# how to load a table query by reference table in EF6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I use entity framework6 and have two entities: Category & Item, which have one-to-many relation, the Item entity has a property `owner`.

That's all, my requirement is to build a query and the results contains all Categories, each of Category contains some of Items which's owner equals to some value.

Category class:

```
public class Category {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? PId { get; private set; }
    [ForeignKey("PId")]
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Category() {
        Subcategories = new List<Category>();
        Items = new List<DataItem>();
    }
}
```

Item class:

```
public class Item {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Owner { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

for example, there have some test data like below:
[image]

Result needs all of those Categories that contain some items owned by 11.
How can I make this query?

Comment: In such a case you may need to use left join Something like: `Category.Id == Item.CategoryId && owner == 11`.

Comment: your are right, but i don't know how to write EF code for this.

Comment: Go through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) msdn document you will have basic Idea about how to left join using linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Category.Items.Filter( item => item.owner == '11')` should do the trick for you, in case I understood the question correctly.

Comment: yes, your answer can work, but this code do filter after query, there will be a waste of query and if Item's count is huge, it will be cause performance poor.

Comment: I thought that the query should be evaluated lazily and hence the filter should be part of the query clause and not filter results in memory. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

```html
var cats = from category in _context.Categories
                           from item in _context.DataItems.Where(i => i.CategoryId == category.Id && i.Owner == id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { Category = category, Items = item };
```

Comment: this code make a left inner join and will create categories tree automatic.